# Structure for "you'll be the first to get informed"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

*You'll be the first to get informed.*

Is this sentence structure correct? May I use either "informed" or "notified" here?

Comment: Yes to all questions, but you shouldn't use the _get_-Passive; it invites inferences about the responsibility of the patient subject that are out of place in an announcement. Use _to be_ instead of _to get._

Answer (score 1):

There is a common idiom; "you'll be the first to know".

Answer (score 0):

The structure is correct. However, *notified* is by far the more common choice and also *to be* instead of *to get* seems more idiomatic to me. In a colloquial context you should probably go for

> You'll be the first to know.

Comment: "You'll be the first to get informed" would be less common than "You'll be the first to be informed."